# CallableStatement in Java return false all the time, but it works on Oracle db

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

my procedure in Oracle:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY USER_LOGIN AS  
   PROCEDURE getUserToLogIn(comp_id NUMBER, user_id APP_USERS.USER_ID%TYPE, pass APP_USERS.ACC_PASSWORD%TYPE) IS 
   pr_comp_id APP_USERS.COMPANY_ID%TYPE;
   pr_user_id APP_USERS.USER_ID%TYPE;
   pr_pass APP_USERS.ACC_PASSWORD%TYPE;
   BEGIN 
      SELECT COMPANY_ID, USER_ID, ACC_PASSWORD INTO pr_comp_id, pr_user_id, pr_pass
      FROM APP_USERS
      WHERE COMPANY_ID = comp_id and USER_ID = user_id and ACC_PASSWORD = pass;
      dbms_output.put_line(pr_comp_id || ' ' || pr_user_id || ' ' || pr_pass); 
   END getUserToLogIn; 
END USER_LOGIN;
```

It returns one record on condition that I paste appropriate credentials. I want to call this procedure in Java, but all the time a variable **found** has a value **false**.

```
    public User getUser(String company_id, String user_id, String acc_password) throws SQLException {
        User user = new User();

        try {
            connection = ConnectionProvider.getConnection();
            callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call USER_LOGIN.getUserToLogIn(?,?,?)}");
            callableStatement.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(company_id));
            callableStatement.setString(2,user_id);
            callableStatement.setString(3,acc_password);

            /*The below part of code has to return true and set this value to "found", 
but procedure does not return true from the Java language level*/
            boolean found = callableStatement.execute();

            while (found) {
                user.setCompany_id(company_id);
                user.setUser_id(user_id);
                user.setAcc_password(acc_password);
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            isClosed = closureProvider.isConnectionClosed(callableStatement,connection);
        }
        return user;
    }
```

What can be a reason of that?

Comment: convert those three local variables `pr_comp_id, pr_user_id, pr_pass` to `OUT` type parameters of the procedure. So, have six parameters for the `callableStatement` within the Java code.

Comment: I changed execute() to executeUpdate() > 0 and it works.